# Calling AudioKit AKMidiSampler.loadMelodicSoundFont asynchronously

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am loading a sound font to the AKMidiSampler via the `try! self.regularBeatSampler.loadMelodicSoundFont("myfile", preset: 0)` method. It takes roughly 7 seconds on the simulator to load the sound font into memory.

I am trying to offload this to the background thread, but I ran into a bunch of issues. Specifically if I do anything while the sound font is loading it still freezes the main thread, so there appears to be some sort of synchronization. I do:

```
let mixer = AKMixer()
myUnrelatedNode >>> mixer
```

and it freezes on connecting to the mixer, until sound font loading is complete. Does anyone know why? Is it a good practice to pre-load the sampler with the SF2 at the app startup and cache it so it's immediately available on a first use?

I am very new to iOS development and AudioKit, so sorry if this is a stupid question.